# legends are getting overlapped for google charts no matter the width of the chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google chart API for displaying charts. I positioned the legends to the bottom of the chart. But legends are getting overlapped no matter what the chart width is.

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Thanks in advance...

The options that I have used is,

```
options = {
            title: chartItemObject.chartName,
            'height' : 230,
            'width' : 410,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start',maxLines : 2 },
            chartArea: {  width: "70%", height: "70%" },
             colors:['#00a4e4','#0070c0','#fdb913','#7030a0','#a06f30','#fd8713','#d9d9d9','#e92828','#0abc01','#00b69d']
    };
```

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem?